# Strict aliasing in flexible array member?

Tags: c, strict-aliasing, flexible-array-member

I'm writing an Arena Allocator and it works, but I feel like it violates strict aliasing rules. I want to know if I'm right or wrong. Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
typedef struct ArenaNode ArenaNode;
struct ArenaNode {
    ArenaNode *next;
    size_t dataSize;
    u8 data[];
};

typedef struct {
    ArenaNode *head;
    ArenaNode *current;
    size_t currentIndex;
} Arena;

static ArenaNode *ArenaNodeNew(size_t dataSize, ArenaNode *next)
{
    ArenaNode *n = malloc(sizeof(ArenaNode) + dataSize);
    n->next = NULL;
    n->dataSize = dataSize;
    return n;
}

void *ArenaAlloc(Arena *a, size_t size)
{
    const size_t maxAlign = alignof(max_align_t);
    size_t offset = nextHigherMultiplePow2(offsetof(ArenaNode, data), maxAlign) - offsetof(ArenaNode, data);
    size_t dataSize = offset + max(size, ARENA_SIZE);
    // first time
    void *ptr;
    if (a->head == NULL) {
        ArenaNode *n = ArenaNodeNew(dataSize, NULL);
        a->head = n;
        a->current = n;
        ptr = n->data + offset;
        a->currentIndex = nextHigherMultiplePow2(offset + size, maxAlign);
    } else {
        // enough space
        if (a->currentIndex + size <= a->current->dataSize) {
            ptr = &a->current->data[a->currentIndex];
            a->currentIndex = nextHigherMultiplePow2(a->currentIndex + size, maxAlign);
        } else {
            ArenaNode *n = ArenaNodeNew(dataSize, NULL);
            a->current->next = n;
            a->current = n;
            ptr = n->data + offset;
            a->currentIndex = nextHigherMultiplePow2(offset + size, maxAlign);
        }
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

The Arena is a linked list of Nodes and a Node is a header followed by data `u8 data[]`. u8 is unsigned char. 
I maintain the next available index (`currentIndex`) and advance `data` by this index and return it as `void *` (`ptr = &a->current->data[a->currentIndex]`). Does this violate strict aliasing rule because I'm converting a pointer to `u8` to something else and using that?

My confusion comes from the fact that memory returned by malloc has no effective type. But since I'm casting the malloc'd pointer to `ArenaNode *` and setting its data members (`next` and `dataSize`) after allocating it (in `ArenaNodeNew`), the effective type becomes `ArenaNode`. Or does it? I didn't set `data` field of that.

Basically, I think the question can be simplified to this: If I malloc a memory region of say, size 10, cast the pointer to `struct {int a;} *` (assume 4 bytes int), set it `a` to something, what happens to the rest of the 6 bytes? Does it have any effective type? Does the presence of flexible array member affect this in any way?

Comment: Where do you actually access the data? Strict aliasing only applies when pointers are de-referenced.

Comment: @Lundin `ArenaAlloc` will be used pretty much like malloc. Eg: `int *a = ArenaAlloc(&arena, sizeof(*a)); *a = 1000;`.

Comment: That itself is not a strict aliasing problem. The problem only rises if you access it as uint8_t and then later as int.

Comment: @Lundin That only works for malloc'd memory, right? If I have a uint8_t local variable, it will be a violation the moment it is accessed as an int, even if I didn't actually previously access it? 
If you can access different parts of malloc'd memory with different types, the compiler keeps track of the offsets and effective type associated with that?

Comment: @WingerSendon: The Effective Type rules are the worst part of C99 and from what I can tell serve no purpose except to sow confusion and discord.  Every possible interpretation will either yield unworkable corner cases, require a compiler to forego many of the optimizations the rules are intended to facilitate, or both.

Answer (score 1):

The extra bytes that are part of the flexible array member will have the effective type of that member as you write to them.

You can safely declare `ptr` as `u8 *` and define your function to return that type as well.

In your example of allocating 10 bytes and treating the first 4 as a struct of the given type, the remaining bytes have no effective type yet.  You can use those for any type, assuming the pointer you use is aligned correctly, i.e. you can point a `int *` to the following bytes but not a `long long *`. due to alignment.

Comment: So, given `struct s {int a; short b}`, if I do: `struct s *p = malloc(sizeof(*p)); p->a=10;`, then `p->b` does not yet have an effective type because I haven't written (or read) from it?. If I access `p->b` like this: `*((char *)p + 4 + 1) = 120;`, there's no issue?

Answer (score 1):

> Does this violate strict aliasing rule because I'm converting a pointer to `u8` to something else and using that?

No, you are not violating strict aliasing, but your code might violate the constraints imposed by [**7.22.3 Memory management functions**, paragraph 1](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3p1):

> The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement and then used to access such an object or an array of such objects in the space allocated ...

You don't appear to be making sure the memory you use for any object is "suitably aligned" for any object.  Given [**6.3.2.3 Pointers**, paragraph 7](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p7)'s statement:

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.

you appear to be risking undefined behavior.

"Suitably aligned" is extremely platform-dependent.

Comment: There's no alignment issue here.  A `struct` with a flexible array member will have sufficient padding for that member.

Comment: @dbush Based on what?  The flexible array in question is a `char` array, likely with no alignment restrictions at all and thus likely to get no padding at all, since the `size_t` and pointer values will likely force the alignment of the structure.  If alignment forced by the pointer/`size_t` combination isn't sufficient to match any larger requirements (for example, a 16-byte alignment restriction for an SSE-type of data on a 32-bit platform, putting the flexible array on an 8-byte offset...), the flexible array will not be "suitably aligned .. for any object".

Comment: From section 6.7.2.1 on "Structure and Union Specifiers" p18: *As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one named member may
have an incomplete array type; this is called a
flexible array member
. In most situations,
the  flexible  array  member  is  ignored.  **In  particular, the  size  of  the  structure  is  as  if  the
flexible  array  member  were  omitted  except  that  it  may  have  more  trailing  padding  than
the omission would imply** .*

Comment: @dbush You can't assume the `char` flexible array is "suitably aligned" based on that as "may" also means "may not".  For example:  https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/i386/malloc-alignment.h.html imposes just that 16-byte alignment I mentioned above on 32-bit x86.  Yet the code posted in the question only ensures 8-byte alignment of the flexible array.

Comment: Flexible array members would be useless if that were the case.  For example, `struct s { short b; };` has size 2 as does `struct s { short b; char c[]; };` but `struct s { short b; long long c[]; };` has size 8.  That's where the alignment comes into play.

Comment: I believe I am calculating the offset within the flexible array to get the correct alignment in the second line of the `ArenaAlloc` function. Isn't `alignof(max_align_t)` what "suitably aligned" means?

Comment: @dbush: Given `typedef struct { long long a; char b[5]; short c[];`} S1;`, it's not possible to perform pointer arithmetic on an `S2*`, the space required for a struct with `N` elements is `(10+2*N)` rounded up to the next multiple of 8, and thus there is no logical benefit to having its reported size of the bare struct padded to the next such (since padding must happen after total the size computation whether or not it was done before).  On the other hand, given `typedef struct { char a; short b[]; } S2`, the struct should contain the padding that would be needed before `b`.